# How to obtain numerical answer for equation containing integration

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

Could some one tell me how to obtain numerical value of $a$ and $b$ from equations below:

$$\frac{1+exp(b)}{1+exp(0.9a+b)}=0.95$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+exp(b)}{1+exp(a x+b)}=1$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: This is a mathematica question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eq1 = (1 + E^b)/(1 + E^(9/10 a + b)) == 95/100;
a0 = a /. Solve[eq1, a] /. C[1] -> 0
f[b1_, x_] := (1 + E^b1)/(1 + E^(x a0 + b1)) /. b -> b1
Quiet@FindRoot[NIntegrate[f[b, x], {x, 0, Infinity}] == 1, {b, -20}]
(* {b -> -29.4444} *)
```

Comment: Something is a little bit unclear to me. What is the reason of using `C[1] -> 0`?

Comment: @barej It should be evident if you type `Solve[eq1, a]` and take a look at the result